# What does admin.autodiscover actually do?

Tags: python, django

I've long been curious about what

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

actually do. [The document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/) didn't say much about it:

> Above we used admin.autodiscover() to automatically load the INSTALLED_APPS admin.py modules.

and

> There is really no need to use autodiscover when using your own AdminSite instance since you will likely be importing all the per-app admin.py modules in your myproject.admin module.

If I don't uncommnet

```
# admin.autodiscover()
```

what functionality I will lose?

And for what consideration should I **use** or **not use** `autodiscover`?

Answer (score 6):

As u said: autodiscover() load all admin.py from the apps folders. So you have in the /admin/ all the models that you use (from your own app or not).

I recommend to use autodiscover() if you are going to use the admin app.

P.D. additionally some app have their on autodiscover with more functionalities.

Comment: Meaning I may override the admin model/view provided by `django.contrib.admin` with my own code?

Comment: No, don't need to override anything. autodiscover() will add autoMAGICALLY more registered app in the admin module. But the code remains the same.

Comment: As a reference the [autodiscover_modules](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/module_loading.py#L51) function is called by `autodiscover()` with `admin` as first positional argument, and `register_to=site` (where `site` is default admin site) as the keyword argument

Answer (score 2):

admin.py is executed whenever your django loads URLconf from urls.py, the autodiscover() will search for all the apps in INSTALLED_APPS one by one and executes the code in that file.